# How does nginx know that tomcat A is down and not to send request to it

Tags: tomcat, nginx, load-balancing

I have 2 tomcat configured at Nginx upstream, and i am facing a problem,
if tomcat A is down, i want all request route to tomcat B or vice versa,

right now what i am doing is:

```
I mark nginx upstream tomcat A entry as DOWN
and reload nginx
after my tomcat A is ready i again unmarked it from DOWN
and reload it.
```

please suggest me any good step as this is a manual work.

eg:

tomcat A,B are actually the Ip address of the machines where these tomcat installed and running.

upstream backend {

```
server Tomcat B
server Tomcat A down;
```

}

Comment: Post your nginx conf

Answer (score -1):

Nginx community version doesn't have the capability of doing failover. i.e. If one node is down, it still routes traffic to that node.

But, Nginx has a health check module. This doesn't come with the normal distribution. But, you can install it. See this page for more details.
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/healthcheck/#

Comment: nginx upstream can find offline(connect timeout or refuse) node and stop routing http traffic to that node. So I think your knowledge about nginx is wrong.

Comment: There are two things I would like to bring up. 1) If we wait for connection timeouts or connection refuses, it ends up with down times for the enduser. 2) If the upstream can detect offline nodes, why does nginx has the option of marking the nodes as down while maintenance?